# How to read .csv file and enable or disable the checkbox by considering column status in C#

Tags: c#, csv, checkbox, enable-if

I have a .csv file like below;

```
Name,Age,Marks0,Marks 1,Marks2,Marks3
Amal,22,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
Nimal,30,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Perera,19,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Sunil,25,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Amali,22,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Ann,26,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Chamath,27,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
Kalana,29,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
Tom,25,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
Jerry,22,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
Peter,23,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
```

So, I want to read this .csv file and check whether the status of Marks0, Marks1, Marks2, Marks3. After that, I want to enable or disable checkbox during the button1 click to browse this file.my interface is like this.
[Interface of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwYbm.png)

In here want to check status of Marks0, Marks1, Marks2, Marks3
the condition is like this, that selected column whole data are TRUE then enable the checkBox.but there are True and False are there then checkBox is enabled.but all are False then checkBox is Disable.

An example in here

Marks0 all are TRUE then  checkBox1 is enable

Marks1 all are TRUE and FALSE then checkBox2 is enable

Marks2 all are  FALSE then checkBox3 is disable

Marks3 all are TRUE and FALSE then checkBox4 is enable
like that, I want to build my code.

I can enable the checkBox whole column is TRUE and  I can disable the checkBox whole column is FALSE  but I can not enable the checkBox that it is TRUE and False like Marks1 and Marks3.please give me a solution for this.

My code is following;

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "*.csv|*.csv";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); //"C:\\BA2000";
        fileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tbOutputFilePath.Text = ofd.FileName;
            fileOriginalOutputPath = tbOutputFilePath.Text;


            if (tbOutputFilePath != null)
            {

                List<Marks> ObservingData = new List<Marks>(); // List to store all available Marks objects from the CSV
                Marks statusInt = new Marks();
                // Loops through each lines in the CSV
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(tbOutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
                {
                    // here line stands for each line in the CSV file

                    string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');

                    statusInt.Mark0 = (InCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark1 = (InCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark2 = (InCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark3 = (InCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

                }

                if (statusInt.Mark0 == false)
                {
                    checkBox1.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (statusInt.Mark1 == false)
                {
                    checkBox2.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (statusInt.Mark2 == false)
                {
                    checkBox3.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (statusInt.Mark3 == false)
                {
                    checkBox4.Enabled = false;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I created a class to store my column value

```
class Marks

    {
        public string Name { get; set; } // property to  store Name
        public int Age { get; set; } // property to store Age 
        public bool Marks0 { get; set; } // property to store Marks0 
        public bool Marks01 { get; set; } // property to store Marks01 
        public bool Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store Marks2 
        public bool Marks3 { get; set; } // property to store Marks3

    }
```

Comment: You want the checkboxes to be checked depending on the values of `statusInt.MarkX` ? Or you want do disable all checkboxes when all of `statusInt.MarkX` are false?

Comment: You should rephrase you problem description for it to be easier to understand. I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But i guess the problem is that all your if statements refer to `statusInt.Mark0` instead of `statusInt.Mark*n*`

Comment: @pitersmx..No I want to enable or disable considering their belong to which checkbox.as an example Mark0 is belong to checkBox1,

Comment: @nozzleman..sorry that's my mistakes.I edited the code

Comment: @nozzleman In here I browse my file clicking the Button1 then get open dialogbox and OK that.then my logic should work.My logic is this.every checkBox belong to one Marks column.as an example Marks0 belong to checkBox1,Marks1 belong to checkBox2,Marks2 belong to checkBox3,Marks3 belong to checkBox4. So In here these Marks column values are true or false.some columns all data are TRUE,some columns all data are FALSE,some columns all data are FALSE or TRUE,Now I want to read this .csv file and check those marks column and look above condition as I mentioned above as an example.

Comment: @nozzleman..sir.can you help me for solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Let me see if I understood you correctly:

if any (or all) `Mark0` is `true` then the checkbox1 is enabled. If ALL are `false` checkbox is disabled. Same rule apply to other marks and checkboxes.

First, you're missing adding statusInt to your `ObservingData` collection. Next, remove all those `if (statusInt.Mark0 == false)` checks because they are checking onyl the lastest row that you have read from csv. To sum things up, this is what needs to be done:

```
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(tbOutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
{
    // here line stands for each line in the CSV file

    string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');
    //init Marks class
    Marks statusInt = new Marks();

    statusInt.Mark0 = (InCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark1 = (InCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark2 = (InCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark3 = (InCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

    //add line read from csv to colletion
    ObservingData.Add(statusInt);
}

//instead of if (statusInt.Mark0 == false), if (statusInt.Mark1 == false) etc, add this
checkBox1.Enabled = ObservingData.Any(m => m.Marks0);
checkBox2.Enabled = ObservingData.Any(m => m.Marks1);
checkBox3.Enabled = ObservingData.Any(m => m.Marks2);
checkBox4.Enabled = ObservingData.Any(m => m.Marks3);
```

Comment: No it's doesn't work.it get all check are enabled with a tick.

Comment: @Nino yes I tried then all check box are disabled.but thank you very much your help sir,I am a C# beginner.If you can please help me to solve this.

Comment: @Nino  In here I browse my file clicking the Button1 then get open dialogbox and OK that.then my logic should work.My logic is this.every checkBox belong to one Marks column.as an example Marks0 belong to checkBox1,Marks1 belong to checkBox2,Marks2 belong to checkBox3,Marks3 belong to checkBox4. So In here these Marks column values are true or false.some columns all data are TRUE,some columns all data are FALSE,some columns all data are FALSE or TRUE,Now I want to read this .csv file and check those marks column and look above condition as I mentioned above as an example.

Comment: @Nino Sir,If you can please give me a help for solving my problem.It is great help for me.

Comment: ok, i think i found an error in your code, you didn't add `statusInt` to `ObservingData`. When you add it, code should work. I have edited my answer, try now.

Comment: @Nino,Thank you very much for your but  here all checkbox enabled yet.please help me.I am a beginner to this language.

Comment: i tried this code with your sample csv... first and last checkboxes are enabled and second and third are disabled. Did you remove your if's?

Comment: @Nino.It is working.thank you so much.Sir.It's very help for me.thank you again for your kind help.

Comment: @Nino sir,there is a problem.There is true and false I previously mentioned.not work this.It works all are false or all are True.please help me.

Comment: @SNP Sorry, I don't understand you. Please clear it to me: If at least one value is true, checkbox have to be enabled? It is disabled only if all values are false?

Comment: @Nino..If at least one value is true, checkbox have to be enabled.and  It is disabled only if all values are false.that's is true in here this code is working for all values are false then disable the checkBOx and all values are true then enable the checkBox.but values are True and false then not work.I can't think why is that.In my example of .csv there checkBox1 should be enabled.checkBox2 should be enabled,checkBox3 should be disabled and checkBox4 should be enabled.Sir,Are you clear that ?now.

Comment: @SNP please understand that people on SO have their life and other responsibilities except for asnwersing question. So, please, don't force and nag for an answer. I have edited answer, because I found error in your old code. To fix it, remove line `Marks statusInt = new Marks();` and put it inside `foreach` loop, under `string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');` like I did in the answer. Now it should work as expected.

Comment: @Nino.pardon me for disturbing you sir,I like to learn this language.I am beginner to this language.So I don't have any person for asking my problems.that's why I asked from you sir,Sorry for my inconvenience.

Comment: @Nino.Sir,If you have time please give me the reason that changed code.What is difference between those changed  'Marks statusInt = new Marks(); ' inside ' foreach ' and outside ' foreach '

Comment: @SNP `foreach` is loop that executes block of code _n_ times (in this example, it will be executed for each line in your csv file. When `statusInt` class is instantiated _outside_ the loop, it is instantiated (let's say created) only _once_. In your loop, you're filling that *only* instance numerous times and then adding that one (only one) to list. Like you have a piece of paper that you're repeatedly writing on and erasing. When you move declaration _inside_ the loop, new `statusInt` is _created_ for every line in your csv, filled and added to list...

Comment: @SNP so, in first case, your `ObservingData` list contains only one item and that item (`statusInt`) is filled with last row. When `statusInt` is moved inside, you'll end with list that contains 11 items, one for each row in your csv. Then, `ObservingData.Any` check if there is at least one Marks0 that is `true`, and if there is, checkbox will be enabled. Same thing is checked for Marks1, Marks2 etc. `ObservingData.Any` will return `false` if there's no `true` values in that collection and checkbox will be disabled.

Comment: @Nino..woow fantastic sir.thank you for your good explanation about that.sorry for disturbing you every time.This is my eager to learn this language.sometimes I got two or three days or sometimes one week for searching mistakes in my coding.little mistakes I could not find in myself.I want to improve that.So thank you thousand time for helping me to solve this problem.